# Difference between "der Tratsch" and "der Klatsch"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I translate *der Tratsch and der Klatsch* as *gossip*.
On Duden I found this example:

> Das ist doch alles nur Klatsch [und Tratsch].

It makes me guess that between the two words there is no difference in meaning.
Is there any difference maybe in the areas or context in which it is used? Or are they really just synonymous?

Comment: In my view they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge it is exactly the same. So they are just synonymous.

Answer (score 4):

The German Wikipedia page for [Klatsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klatsch) makes an interesting distinction:

*Klatsch* is explicitly talking about *a third person*.

*Tratsch*, on the other hand, is described more generally as an *aimless conversation*.